# Django-bitfield : Access a bitfield in django queryset values

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-queryset, django-bitfield

I was trying to list of values of a bitfield in a django queryset but was unable to do so as i couldn't find anything related to fetching bitfield flag values.

Let's say I have a field in one of my models

```
flags = Bitfield(flags=( 'a', 'b'))
```

now I want to use this value from a queryset

is there a way to get the value in the queryset by doing something like this

```
m=model.objects.values('flags__a__is_set')
```